# There are at most finitely many square-free integers $d\not\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is a Euclidean field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

My book's exercise is about proving that there are at most finitely many square-free integers $d\not\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is a Euclidean field (with respect to the norm).

Using a later exercise it translates to the following elementary problem:

> There are at most finitely many square-free integers $d\not\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ having the following property: $\forall x, y\in \mathbb{Q}, \ \exists a, b\in\mathbb{Z}\ \text{ such that }\ |(x-a)^2 - d(y-b)^2| < 1$.

It's not hard to solve it for $d < 0$. I know that the biggest $d$ satisfying it is $d = 73$, so I tried proving that all $d > 100$ do not satisfy the property, but I got stuck.

Comment: what book would that be?

Answer (score 1):

This was proved independently by Fox and Berg in 1935 and is not trivial; see
this [survey](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/survey.pdf) for references. You will need to exploit the fact that $2$ ramifies since the case $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ is definitely a very difficult case.